# Удаление пользователя ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, users, asp.net-identity-2

Пытаюсь удалить пользователя:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await userManager.DeleteAsync(user);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Error"] = "Error!";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

            TempData["Error"] = "Error!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Пользователь не удаляется. Происходит ошибка:

> **System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException**: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> **System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException**: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.ClientProfiles_dbo.AspNetUsers_Id". The conflict occurred in database "Schedule", table "dbo.ClientProfiles", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

Пытался удалять сначала роль, а потом самого пользователя, но ошибка все равно происходит. Как ее исправить?

Comment: Вам придется изменить требования к внешнему ключу "FK_dbo.ClientProfiles_dbo.AspNetUsers_Id", видимо, на каскадное удаление. А вообще удаление пользователей системы - неверная практика, удалять пользователей нельзя, нужно делать их неактивными (добавить поле IsActive в таблицу юзеров), вы удаляете пользователя, а что происходит с его записями и активностями в остальной части БД? Тоже удалять? А потом пересчитывать индексы?

Comment: @Bulson, большое спасибо за комментарий! Вместо удаления делаю пользователей неактивными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написали в комментариях:

> удаление пользователей системы - неверная практика

Так что вместо удаления, я делаю пользователей неактивными.

В `UserManager` надо прописать:

```
UserManager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true; //разрешает блокировку пользователей
UserManager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100).TimeOfDay; //время блокировки
```

Далее, когда я хочу заблокировать пользователя:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LockOut(string id)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

        if (user != null)
        {
            user.LockoutEnabled = true;
            await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```